# C++ generic realtime text interface library

Tags: c++, text, command-line-interface

Silly question here, I'm looking for a generic text based API for command-line programs. Something like `ncurses` I *think* would fit the bill. In an ideal world, I would like something portable, between windows and linux, but for now, it'll only be running in linux.

Since this is probably horribly vague, here's what I have so far and where I want to go.

What I have so far:

- Code that creates a realtime display area in a linux terminal. The display area is about 50 rows by 100 columns or so, and is backed by a character array buffer of the same size. I `cout` the text 20 times a second, each time preceeded by the bash code for moving the cursor "up" 50 rows (that is, `cout << "\033[50A";`).
- This works great to create a real time updating display with only minimal flicker, but I have no way of sending input into the program that I can think of (via the terminal, that is).

Where I want to go:

- Use some more heavy duty appropriate library that might manage the buffer for me and printing the screen, hopefully getting rid of the super special bash `\033[50A` code.
- Add a command line input to the bottom of the screen, where the user can, while the screen is updating, type in certain commands to cause the program to take certain actions.

I've seen other programs do this, how do they do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the ["readline" library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_readline) does much of what you're wanting.